# Access Object in main Activity with a different class in android

Tags: java, android

I am working on a small android project. I have a textbox on the screen ( given the ID lblDisplay).

I have a separate class, that I want to make an instance of and have it be able to enter text into the lblDisplay `EditText` Object.

How can I do this? 
I noticed that when I tried the way i did on in my `Activity` class, 
 `EditTxt eText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lblDisplay)` 
It would not let me, as it can not find the `findViewById()` method, I assume I get that as I am not extending Activity, and I can't Extend Activity as I am Extending `TimerTask`.  Can someone point me in the right direction so I can get my new class to be able to enter text into the textbox on my main class?

The new class is a `TimerTask` which I want to be able to update the screen every few seconds.  I really hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks. 
Scott

EDIT: Posting Code:

Here is the New class I made.

```
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;





public class ARCTimer extends TimerTask {

private Context context;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
public SeekBar skVelo;
public SeekBar skAngle;
public EditText etDisplay;
public Double tTime = 0.1;

public ARCTimer(Context con, SeekBar sVelo, SeekBar sAngle, EditText eDisplay){
    this.context = con;
    this.skVelo = sVelo;
    this.skAngle = sAngle;
    this.etDisplay = eDisplay;

}

@Override
public void run() {
    //CODE HERE
    //LETS UPDATE THE TIME AND DISPLAY SO WE CAN SEE IF THE TIMER IS WORKING PROPERLY

    //FIRE BUTTON CODE START

    //TESTING VALUES

    Double dVelo = Double.valueOf(skVelo.getProgress());

    dVelo = dVelo/100;

    Double dAngle = Double.valueOf(skAngle.getProgress());


    //Make an instance of the ARC class
    ARC arc = new ARC();
    //Lets set the values we will need
    arc.setV(dVelo);
    arc.setA(dAngle);
    arc.setG(9.8);
    arc.setT(tTime);


    Double dY = arc.getY();
    Double dX = arc.getX();
    Double dXMax = arc.getXmax();

    String sMsg = "";
    sMsg += "At Time: "+ tTime.toString().substring(0, 3) + " . Y = "+  dY.toString().substring(0, 4) + ". X = " +dX.toString().substring(0, 4) 
            + ". Max = " + dXMax.toString().substring(0, 3);

    //EditText eResult = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lblResult);
    etDisplay.setText("Hello World!");


    tTime+= 0.1; // INCREASE TIME FOR TESTING PURPOSES



    //FIRE BUTTON CODE END
    new Thread(new Runnable() { //THREAD ????
        @Override
        public void run() {
                //CODE FOR THREAD GOES IN HERE

        }
    }).start();


}

}
```

Here is the code I am using to start the timer

```
Timer tmr = new Timer();
ARCTimer udpateSelf = new    ARCTimer(MainActivity_MooseCannon.this,skVelo,skAngle,eResult);
tmr.scheduleAtFixedRate(udpateSelf, 0, 2000);
```

I tried passing the objects to the constructor,  no idea if this would work or not. The app doesn't seem to crash when getting the value from the seekbar though.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Well, as any Android programmer knows, you need an Activity (or Fragment within an Activity) to host a view, so somewhere you have to have an Activity or your application won't work. So, do you have an Activity? If so, please post the code. You shouldn't be tyring to host a View from a TimerTask subclass.

Comment: I've posted the code for you.

Comment: I'm not hosting the view from the subclass, i have an activity class that calls my custom timer class, in that customer timertask class i am trying to enter text into a text box. It works fine from my main activity class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not making your `TimerTask` an inner class of you `Activity` ? You'll have access to 'findViewById' method then.
Alternatively, you could pass your `Activity` or the `TextView` to the `TimerTask`.

---

As a response to one comment below : once you've fixed your first problem (the one you ask for), you also need to update the text via the Ui Thread. This can be achieved like this (supposing you used the inner class solution)

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        EditText eResult = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lblResult);
        eResult.setText(sMsg); // Note that 'sMsg' as to be made 'final' to be used this way
    }
}
```

Comment: You still cannot access the UI from the thread on which a TimerTask runs

Comment: yea, i tried passing the objects for the edit texts to the sub class. I think i may have to make it an inner class, i als o tried passing the activity it's self, it still crashes when i try to set the text thou. So i'm gonna play aroudn with it i guess, i'll try setting it up as an inner class soon.

Comment: I know, but he didn't ask for that. Of course, it is required to call `setText` from the Ui Thread, which can be achieve using my example by adding an extra `runOnUiThread(Runnable)`, the `Runnable` actually calling through `TextView.setText`

Comment: I tried an inner class and i am getting the same thing. Looking into the error log, the subclass cannot touch the view, as only the main class can. Am i doing something wrong? i feel like i am doing something wrong here.

Comment: I already addressed this issue by editing the original post : you cannot use `setText`outside the Ui Thread. You should use then `Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)` or `View.post(Runnable)` and the given `Runnable` will run on Ui Thread.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update SeekBar (as well as any other View) outside UI thread. That's why you don't see the changes.
TimerTask's *run()* method is fired in a different thread.

One way is posting a Runnable to a UI thread using Handler.

make sure the Handler is created with UI thread looper

```
mHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
```

Every time you need to update the SeekBar, post the Runnable

```
mHandler.post(new UpdateSeekBarRunnable(skVelo, progress));
```

And the Runnable itself:

```
private static final class UpdateSeekBarRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final SeekBar mSeekBar;
    private final int mValue;

    UpdateSeekBarRunnable(final SeekBar seekBar, final int value) {
        this.mSeekBar = seekBar;
        this.mValue = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mSeekBar.setProgress(mValue);
    }

}
```